# Volume group "luks" not found

Tags: debian, systemd, apt, grub, luks

OS: Parrot OS

VM: Qemu

Filesystem: Btrfs

This is caused due to an improper reboot before full apt upgrade.

After the reboot and entering in the Luks partition password. It successfully decrypts and then stays at the loading screen "Cryptsetup: luks-the-correct-id: set up successfully".

When I press F12 to see what the console is saying, it gives me this Error:

> ```
> Volume group "luks" not found
> Cannot process volume group luks
> [!!!!!!] Failed to mount API filesystems
> Cryptsetup: luks-the-correct-id: set up successfully
> ```

When I go through grub to the advanced options and select the recovery kernel I get extra output which I will summarize:

> ```
> systemd[1]: failed to mount tmpfs at /dev/shm
> systemd[1]: failed to mount tmpfs at /run/lock
> ```

Not sure what else to put in this question. As the title says, I have not been dropped into emergency shell or have had any luck figuring out, how to update the system properly through grub.

Also I do realize on my part this is a fault in which I did not save a snapshot of the VM prior to the update/reboot nor setup a script for it.

UPDATE[0]: I got initramfs shell with access to some files through the kernel ACPI off option.

UPDATE[1]: Seeing as tmpfs cannot be mounted I searched up this resource: [Toradex - Initramfs and tmpfs](https://developer-archives.toradex.com/knowledge-base/initramfs-and-tmpfs). Still unsure what to do with it, but I'll read up some more.

UPDATE[2]: My /etc/crypttab:

> luks-the-correct-id UUID=the-correct-id  /crypto_keyfile.bin
> luks,discard,keyscript=/bin/cat

I was looking for a storage device, but seeing as I am using a VM, Im not sure what device parrot os usually uses. Can't seem to find any vda files in /dev/

Comment: Hard to tell you want you need to do, since we have no idea how LUKS, LVM and everything was setup on  your system.  I would probably try to boot some kind of livecd or rescue image in that VM from an attached ISO and look at the partitions and so on, and see if you can mount things.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks for the reply. I am going down that route and seem to have access to my files. I am currently creating a backup, but at the same time it seems that the "sudo chroot /media/live-os/uuid" isn't working and gives output "/usr/bin/zsh file or directory not found". I am using kali as the live medium because it has an easy cryptopen gui that does most of the work for me.

Comment: Did you have zsh installed on your system?  If not, then do `sudo chroot path bash` to force bash instead of letting it try to find zsh in the chroot.